# Better practice of workaround for implementing a type field in Java

Tags: java, database-design, spring

We have a class in our company's main library as follows:

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private UserType type;
    // Getters, setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

and have several options to implement `UserType`. One of which is an `enum`:

```
public enum UserType {
    DEFAULT (10),
    TYPE_A  (20);

    private int type;

    UserType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public static UserType valueOf(int value){

        for(UserType type : values()){
            if(type.getType() == value){
                return type;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Couldn't convert value : %d into a valid %s object", value, UserType.class));
    }
}
```

Our `USERS` table:

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
|  1 |   10 |
|  2 |   20 |
+----+------+
```

We have a `RowMapper<User>` again, in our library which is as follows:

```
public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        return new User(rs.getLong("id"), UserType.valueOf(rs.getInt("type"));
    }
}
```

However, a project that takes the main library as a dependency might need to extend `UserType`. Converting `UserType` into an interface, again doesn't work, because of `RowMapper` (again in the library) will have to instantiate a `UserType`.

Here's what I come up with:

```
public class UserType {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // Getters, setters and constructors
}
```

and the database becomes:

`USERS`:

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
|  1 |   10 |
|  2 |   20 |
+----+------+
```

`USER_TYPES`:

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
| 10 | DEFAULT |
| 20 | TYPE_A  |
+----+---------+
```

and in `RowMapper` we create a user as follows:

```
return new User(rs.getLong("id"), new UserType(rs.getInt("type_id"), rs.getString("type_name")));
```

and for utility, we could a have a `UserTypeContainer`:

```
public class UserTypeContainer {
    public static final UserType DEFAULT = new UserType(10, "DEFAULT");
    public static final UserType TYPE_A = new UserType(10, "TYPE_A");
}
```

so that one could make use of it:

```
someUserDao.find(UserTypeContainer.DEFAULT);
```

and the projects that have this library as dependency will have to:

1) Have the extended types in their database
2) Extend `UserTypeContainer` to have their extended types (if they want to make use of the line above)

Is this an optimal solution? Is this a good programming practice, or do you see any flaws? What other options do I have?

**Update:**

I need to come up with a reusable `RowMapper` contained by the library. And I started to think that this is not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `RowMapper` take an optional UserType factory/creator/builder. If RowMapper encounters a UserType it's unfamiliar with, pass it to the factory (if one was given.)

To clarify, I would make UserType a class but it could still look like an enum:

```
class UserType {
  public static final UserType DEFAULT = new UserType(10);
  public static final UserType TYPE_A = new UserType(20);

  private int typeId;

  protected UserType(int typeId) {
     this.typeId = typeId;
  }
}
```

Then, define a FunctionInterface as an argument...

```
@FunctionInterface
interface UserTypeCreator {
   UserType create(ResultSet rs); // I don't actually recommend using ResultSet as an argument
}
```

Then your DAO takes that interface as an argument to the constructor.

```
class SomeDao {
   private Optional<UserTypeCreator> customTypeCreator;

   public SomeDao(UserTypeCreator customTypeCreator) {
      this.customTypeCreator = Optional.ofNullable(customTypeCreator);
   }

   public UserType create(ResultSet rs) {
      int type = getType(rs);
      switch (type) {
          case 10:
             return UserType.DEFAULT;
          case 20:
             return UserType.TYPE_A;
          default:
             return customTypeCreator
                         .orElseThrow(UnknownUserTypeException::new)
                         .create(rs);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which would be better in terms of implementing `UserType`, an `enum` or an actual `class` with `id` and `name` fields? Could you elaborate a bit more on if I should implement the different `User` classes or not, and how a utility class would look like so that the consumers of the library could use methods like `someUserDao.find(UserTypeContainer.DEFAULT);`? I'd greatly appreciate a bit more complete answer.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral added some more detail.